# How do I include Maven assembly execution specific expressions in an assembly descriptor file?

Tags: build-process, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I currently have two assembly descriptors with two executions for my project which generates distributions of the project for two different groups:

```
      <!-- Client distribution -->
      <execution>
        <id>client</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <descriptors>
            <descriptor>src/main/assembly/dist-client.xml</descriptor>
          </descriptors>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
      <!-- Developer distribution -->
      <execution>
        <id>developer</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <descriptors>
            <descriptor>src/main/assembly/dist-developer.xml</descriptor>
          </descriptors>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
```

That means I have to maintain two sets of descriptors, shell scripts etc, which I want to avoid, but I can't seem to find a way of getting a expression containing execution id or another configuration parameter unique to the execution to the descriptor.

I'd assume that if the expression is visible to the assembly, the plugin will also be able to substitute it into my shell scripts to consolidate the build into one dist assembly descriptor with two executions.

Can anyone suggest a better approach?

Comment: Have you taken a look to filtering? http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/single/filtering-some-distribution-files.html with this you can configure different property files in the different executions... (Take a look here: https://github.com/khmarbaise/CIEnv/tree/master/hudson/cienv-proxy may be this helps.)

Comment: I'm using filters to substitute in the distributable jar filename, and they're definitely part of the solution, but I also need the final filename, the destination shell script names etc to represent the execution. For instance 'myclientapp' vs 'mydevapp'. Its a command line app and I display different available actions depending on the distribution type passed in on a system parameter.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the total answer, but you could at least make this situation better by using a [**descriptor component**](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/component.html).  A descriptor component is a portion of an assembly descriptor file that is intended to be reused amongst several descriptors.

Perhaps between the filtering and the descriptor component you can limit the amount of items that need to go into each of the assembly descriptor files.

Comment: Actually, my assembly files aren't that complex, I wanted to avoid duplicating the shell scripts mostly, because they're quite complex. I took a look through the assembly interpolation code: there's no way to achieve this currently in the way I envisioned, nothing execution specific makes it to the interpolator.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what these shell scripts are and what they do?